# Regular expression of a languageof two letters that must alternate?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

Let be a language with the following alphabet : $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$

{ $w$ | $w$ does not contains $aa$ nor $bb$}

I know it can be graphed this way :

[image]

Can I write it as the following regular expression ?

$$(ab)^*+(ba)^*$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're missing $aba$ and $bab$ etc.

Obviously, we're looking for words of one of the forms

- $ababa…ba$
- $ababa…b$
- $baba…ba$
- $baba…b$

That translates to the RE

$(ab)^*a + (ab)^* + b(ab)^* + b(ab)^*a$

<sub>In CS, this is easier written as $a?(ba)^*b?$, when the $?$ modifier is available.</sub>

Comment: Your CS expression can be written as $(1 + a)(ba)^*(1+b)$, where $1$ is the empty word.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Is the empty word compulsory ?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica The set description of your language includes the empty word $\epsilon$, as the empty string does not contain the letters sequences $aa$ or $bb$. However, the picture of the finite automaton you provided does not recognize the empty word, as its initial state is not accepting. So in fact, the picture and the set description you gave are in conflict.